# Populate JS array from returned PHP/JSON

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json

I have a `JSON` encoded array, to which i am returning to an `AJAX` request.

I need to place the `JSON` array into a JS Array so i can cycle through each array of data to perform an action.

**Q.** How do i place the `JSON` array contents into a `JS` array efficiently?

**The PHP/JSON Returned to the AJAX**

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
     FROM btn_color_presets
    ';

$result = mysqli_query($sql);

$array = array(); // 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) // 
{
     $array[] = $row;
     $index++;
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function to do so:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(response_from_php);

// loop over each item
for (var i in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       console.log(myObject[i]);
    }
}
```

You can also use [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) if you are using jQuery, however jQuery also uses same function [under the hood](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.parseJSON) as priority if available.

Comment: Thanks for the response. so, to clarify i do not require console log i can do my actions there in place of that.. correct? I am appending css to the document with the contents of the array.

Comment: @StuartWickenden: Yes you are right, `console.log` is used here as an example to see result of each time but you can replace as per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Safraz answer:

If you're using `jQuery`, there's another way to do that. Simply add `json` as last parameter to your `ajax` calls. It tells `jQuery` that some `json` content will be returned, so `success` function get already parsed `json`.

Below example shows you simple way to achieve this. There's simple `json` property accessing (`result.message`), as well as `each` loop that iterates through whole array/object. If you will return more structurized json, containing list of object, you can access it inside `each` loop calling `value.objectfield`.

Example:

```
//Assuming, that your `json` looks like this:
{
    message: 'Hello!',
    result: 1
}

$.post(
    'example.com',
    {data1: 1, data2: 2},
    function(response){
        console.log(response.message) //prints 'hello'
        console.log(response.result) //prints '1'

        //iterate throught every field in json:
        $(response).each(function(index, value){
            console.log("key: " + index + " value: " + value); 
        });
    },
    'json'
)
```